# Which update from Windows Update Catalog

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, software-update

According to Settings >> System >> About I have currently:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 1703
- OS Build: 15063.850
- System type:x64-based processor

Which of these updates do I have to install?
[Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=windows%2010%201703%20x64)

I've tried to install all files classified as "Updates" but always get an error "**The update is not applicable to your computer**"

So what update do I have install to get the "Feature upgrade version 1709"?

Comment: Generally, when there is a big download in Windows update, I copy the KB number and download it from Update Catalog. Because IDM download faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what update do I have install to get the "Feature upgrade version 1709"?

**None of them**

You cannot download the Windows 1709 Feature Update from the Windows Catalog website.  If you want the update to Windows 10 Version 1709 you only have four options.

1. The first is download it through Windows Update.
2. The second is download the current 1709 ISO and install it from within Windows.  You can do that by visiting [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) page.
3. The third is to use the [Upgrade Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-fall-creators-update) tool.
4. The fourth would be to use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10)

It is also available through Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) and Windows Update for Business

Comment: Thank you but the Windows 10 Update Assistant seems to have the same problem as the regular Windows Update. At about 55% it reboots the PC and shortly afterwards it begin to restore to the previous version. NO reason is given! The [Update histotry](http://public-ftp.gumtreegully.com.au/uploads/win10_update_history.jpg) just lists "Failed to install" But I already know that :-)  **Anybody know where to find more details?**

Comment: Tahnks. But I'll give this "Feature upgrade" a miss.