# How to Insert Manually Updates into Windows 10 Pro installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

We have Windows 10 Pro and we have no option to push updates to the computers.
We have Windows Server 2003 that does not support updates for Windows 10 clients.
Have to say it is not related to Windows 10 Upgrades.
In addition, i checked and none of the following [**in that solution**](https://superuser.com/questions/1283004/which-update-from-windows-update-catalog) was working.

I have problem when installing new computers:

When i make new install on a new computer- the updates start to download (after installation) in about 3 hours on each computer. Time i dont have.

I thought, maybe i can located those updates manually and locally on a computer that allready have those updates and import them into my installation via **[NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/download/)**.
Cant locate the updates locally though.

I know i have [**Windows Catalog**](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) but somehow, when i trying to search in **Windows Update history** for lets just say:

> Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803

I **cant** located its **KB** number to download from Windows Catalog. And it happens in all big windows 10 updates.

Where do i locate those updates locally exept Windows Catalog, or is there another way to make that happend?

Comment: "We have Windows 10 Pro and we have no option to push updates to the computers." Why? Pushing updates (using Windows Server Update Services [WSUS]) is the official, recommended and supported way of installing multiple computers efficiently. Please edit to explain why you cannot use that - that will help us suggest other options.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: You cannot locate 1803 in the Windows Catalog because it doesn't exist in the Windows Catalog.  You should consider 1803 a new version of Windows, because when you update Windows 10 Version 1709 to Windows 10 Version 1803, Windows is performing an in place upgrade to that version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which update from Windows Update Catalog](https://superuser.com/questions/1283004/which-update-from-windows-update-catalog).  Different Feature Update, but same answers, so to avoid submitting a duplicate answer I am going to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: I have checked, and none of the following **in that solution** was working.

Comment: Download it using the media creation tool....https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-1803/#Download_Windows_10_Version_1803_using_Windows_Media_Creation_Tool